# Error running apache2

Tags: server, apache2

When I run the command: `sudo service apache2 status` I get this error:

```
Dec 15 22:37:26 raspberrypi apache2[17459]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!
Dec 15 22:37:26 raspberrypi apache2[17459]: The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Dec 15 22:37:26 raspberrypi apache2[17459]: Output of config test was:
Dec 15 22:37:27 raspberrypi apache2[17459]: apache2:   
 Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:225: <FilesMatch> was not closed.
Dec 15 22:37:27 raspberrypi apache2[17459]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Dec 15 22:37:27 raspberrypi apache2[17459]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 15 22:37:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 15 22:37:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Dec 15 22:37:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
Dec 15 22:40:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

On my file I have at that line:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

put `\.php$` in double quotes

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

restart `apache2`:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

if that's wouldn't fix the problem change `FilesMatch` to `LocationMatch` and then restart `apache2`

```
<LocationMatch "\.php$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: It worked for me when I changed FilesMatch to LocationMatch, but can you explain why this would make a difference?

Comment: Location directives match based on the HTTP request URI).
Directory and Files directives, on the other hand, match based on whether there is a directory path or file in the filesystem of the DocumentRoot that matches to respective part of the the HTTP request URI

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. However, the error message is "<FilesMatch> was not closed" even though there is a clear `</FilesMatch>` statement two lines down. Is that a bug, do you think?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you copy-pasted the content. Instead, type the below manually in the `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
     SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Sometimes the Enter in Windows, Linux, and web page looks the same, but in reality, the characters used are not ASCII compatible with the OS you use.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the ./php as "./php"

Dont use FilesMatch on last line .

It will give error , if u use FilesMatch on last line .

Use your required FilesMatch , below the FilesMatch ^.ht as shown below

`<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>`

i send my code and it works fine too for me .
[here is my code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmdPZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

I don't know what happened with that file and/or apache.
I made some changes through ssh using nano, but i think i didn't even touched that specific file.

Anyway, i reinstalled apache2 and it's working again.